# Ellipses of the preoposition IN, in the given sentence

Tags: grammar

Like we say "what time do we get off work?", could one say **"what month do you leave for Europe"** ?

I have heard people say stuff like **"what day is your flight?"**, but I haven't heard anyone say the same concerning months, so I got curious.

Comment: What does your question have to do with "ellipsis of the preposition IN"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use any measure of time that you'd like. (Day, week, month, and year all work for asking about somebody's future trip.)

However, using some units of time, while grammatically correct, will not actually be meaningful in a normal sense. For example, nobody would typically ask, "What minute do you leave for Europe?" (The response would likely be something like, "What? I don't know what you mean.") However, it is possible that somebody could ask (in a certain context), "At what minute after the hour does your flight leave?" Or, "What is the departure time of your flight?" (The former requests an exact number of minutes, while the latter will produce an hour as well as a—perhaps imprecise—number of minutes.)